# Error inflating custom ViewPager via axml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a custom ViewPager which will prevent user from scrolling, as it should move only programmatically, according to another classic ViewPager. Links between the two pagers are working when I use two classic pagers, I just need to remove touch handling on one of them (if there is any solution simpler than creating a custom pager to achieve that, it won't exactly answer the question but still be a valid solution to my problem)

Here is my custom pager class :

```
namespace MyApplication.Droid
{
    public class NonSwipeableViewPager : ViewPager
    {
        public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) :
            base(context)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base(context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public NonSwipeableViewPager(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) :
            base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

According to this, the fully qualified name of my class is

> MyApplication.Droid.NonSwipeableViewPager

And here is my attempt to use it in an AXML layout :

```
<myapplication.droid.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/nonSwipeableViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

But the result is always the same. According to the stack trace (see below), the class cannot be found.

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class myapplication.droid.NonSwipeableViewPager ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "myapplication.droid.NonSwipeableViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.myapplication-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.company.myapplication-1, /system/lib]]
at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "myapplication.droid.NonSwipeableViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.myapplication-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.company.myapplication-1, /system/lib]]
at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at at md55dff054c92df00b604ae7ee631274a9a.AppointmentRequestFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
at at md55dff054c92df00b604ae7ee631274a9a.AppointmentRequestFragment.onCreateView(AppointmentRequestFragment.java:35)
at at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

First, I didn't know that I had to lowercase the namespace in axml (from MyApplication.Droid to myapplication.droid).

I tried several things, like keeping case according to namespace, going full lowercase except for class name, only lowering first letter of each part of the namespace, but everything lead to the same error, and I have no idea why. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error inflating class myapplication.droid.NonSwipeableViewPager

As you have point out, you should use the fully qualified name of your custom class like this :

```
<MyApplication.Droid.NonSwipeableViewPager
     android:id="@+id/nonSwipeableViewPager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the last part of my post, I tried several things like MyApplication, myApplication, myapplication, and all resulted in the same error which is in the post. And I saw here and there on SO and on Xamarin forums that namespaces have to be lowercased in axml in order to work. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: @YumeYume, that's strange, it should be work. Could you please share your basic demo that could reproduce this problem, to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: @YumeYume, you have try use the qualified name like `MyApplication.Droid.NonSwipeableViewPager` and still have the same error? It must be exactly same with your `NonSwipeableViewPager`'s namespace.

Comment: Ok, I kinda feel dumb actually. Indeed this is working, though I've seen almost everywhere that I should lowercase the namespace to fit in an axml file, but apparently not. But that wasn't my problem actually. Due to some bad git flow management, the file containing my class wasn't included in the project. A simple readding of the file to the project, and everything is working. Marking your answer as valid as I now know whether I should lowercase the namespace or not.

Comment: [Register("lowercase.namespace.InstantAutoCompleteTextView")] on top of custom class solved it for me.